# 3 pairs v.s. 2 pairs?

Tags: texas-hold-em

i was playing world poker on xfinity internet apps and i think this was considered texas holdem. I had in my hand a 4 and a 7. The first 3 cards the dealer dealt on the table were a 4, Queen, and a 7. So i now have two pairs which are the 4's and 7's. The next two cards dealt on the table were both 3's. i was then competing with one other better and we kept raising the bet. Finally, the cards in his hand and my hand were revealed and he had a Queen and another card that didnt match up with the table. So now he has 2 pairs, Queens and 3's. Why did they give him the win????!!!!!,,,, when i had 3 pairs compared to his 2 pairs??? I had the 4's,7's, {and now with those last 2 cards being the same number,} 3's.
Why didnt i win with 4's, 7's and 3's to his Q's and 3's????????

Comment: you always play the best 5 Cards, there is no 3 pair possible. The person with the higher pair out of 2 pair wins. Example:  player 1 has a pair of Kings and a pair of queens, while player 2 has a pair of aces and a pair of Aces. Player 2 wins with Aces and deuces.

Answer (score 1):

3 pair is not a poker hand, the other player had a better 2 pair (Qs and 3s is better than 7s and 4s)

Comment: How do you get a full house out of that hand?

Comment: misread what the board was, corrected now